# Why text in the EditText disappearing when i click back...?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ExpandableListView in which i am loading my custom views having 3 edit text fields.

After entering the values into those edit texts,

i am clicking back to minimize the soft keyboard.

That time the text in the edit boxes is disappearing Why..?

If anybody have any idea please help me..?

This is my getGroupView method of ExpandableListView

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("Position = " + groupPosition);
        if (groupPosition == 0) {
            if (firstTime) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pay_credit_card,
                        parent, false);
                checkBox1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                email = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
                phone1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph);
                phone2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                checkBox1.setOnClickListener(headListener);
                firstTime = false;
            } else {
                emailSt = email.getText().toString();
                phone1St = phone1.getText().toString();
                phone2St = phone2.getText().toString();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pay_credit_card,
                        parent, false);
                checkBox1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                email = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
                phone1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph);
                phone2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                checkBox1.setOnClickListener(headListener);
                email.setText(emailSt);
                phone1.setText(phone1St);
                phone2.setText(phone2St);
            }
            return convertView;
        } else {

            View v = null;
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pay_group_head, parent, false);
            String gt = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
            if (gt != null && tv2 != null)
                tv2.setText(gt);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Please post some code and XML, otherwise it will not be possible to help you.

Comment: I guess the ListView is reloading the data and if you haven't saved the textinput, it will be deleted

Comment: @banzai86 Ya you are right, thats what happening. How to avoid that.

Comment: After each textinput, save the text to a string-array or something similar, so that your ListView can retreive the data when it reloads the table

Comment: @banzai I tried what you said, but still same problem, Look at my code and suggest me. I have updated my code.

Comment: emailSt = email.getText().toString(); email.setText(emailSt); This doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @banzai can you please suggest what should i change...!

Comment: @banzai I have changed the code, Now its working Thankyou....!

Comment: @banzai Answer this to my question, I will accept you will some reputations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already posted as comment:

In order to solve the problem of vanishing textinput, you need to save the textinput directly to some kind of string-array or similar which allows the ListView to retreive the data when it reloads the table

Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the dictionary option and see.
and if you want to save the contents in the edit text then you have to use shared preference or other similar saving options.